# How to visually simulate a Queue(data structure) with java?

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, awt

I need to simulate Queue's with java. I just want to know if there is any easier way to do it than drawing whole animation with draw() function.

Edit : It is a homework and i need to make a visual simulation. The program will vusally show how queue is working.

Comment: Java already has a `Queue` interface (and a bunch of implementations thereof) - why do you need to simulate one? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What does it mean to "simulate a Queue", and what does this have to do with a GUI?

Comment: What does a queue have to do with the paint() function?

Comment: what do you mean by simulate?

Comment: It is a homework and i need to make a visual simulation. The program will vusally show how queue is working.

Comment: i think the OP need a simulation of how a queue works. Homework?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) or [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) that contains items in your queue. You'll have to figure out how to use those components, but it would be easier than raw painting.

Comment: I second this approach - creating a JListModel that has a queue add() and remove() operation would be dirt simple.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/DataStructures/Lessons/QueuesImplementationView/applet.html) out... It's an applet but you can do it with swing too...

ADD:
You don't have to draw the whole animation... you can do it with simple labels...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawling it you could add components to a GUI.  But depending on how you simulate it painting it might be the best course of action.